# Interleave two arrays (card decks) using recursion... I was able to solve it without recursion but want to know what I am doing wrong

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, merge, shuffle

I am attempting to write a function that takes two arrays as inputs, representing the top and bottom halves of a deck of cards, and shuffles them together using recursion. I am attempting return a single array containing the elements from both input arrays interleaved, like so:

- the first element should be the first element of the first input
  array
- the second element should be the first element of the second input
  array,
- the third element should be the second element of the first input
  array,
- the fourth element should be the second element of the second array,

...etc.

I want to append any remaining elements to the end of the array.

This is how I solved it without recursion:

```
function shuffleCards(topHalf, bottomHalf) {
  let returnArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(topHalf.length, bottomHalf.length); i++) {
    if (topHalf[i]) {
      returnArray.push(topHalf[i]);
    }
    if (bottomHalf[i]) {
      returnArray.push(bottomHalf[i]);
    }
  }
  return returnArray
}
```

and this is my attempt with recursion:

```
function shuffleCards(topHalf, bottomHalf) {
  let results = [];
  if (topHalf.length) {
    results.push(topHalf[0]
    } 
  if (bottomHalf.length) {
      results.push(bottomHalf[0])
    }
  return results.concat(shuffleCards(topHalf.slice(1), bottomHalf.slice(1)));
}
```

I keep getting the syntax error "missing ) after argument list" but I am fairly certain all of the parenthesis are in the write place.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: `results.push(topHalf[0]` is missing its closing parenthesis (set up linting in your editor of choice)

Answer (score 4):

Beside missing parenthesis, you could take only the first item from the first half and call the function with swapped arrays.

```js
function shuffleCards([value, ...topHalf], bottomHalf) {
    return value === undefined
        ? [...bottomHalf]
        : [value, ...shuffleCards(bottomHalf, topHalf)];
}

console.log(...shuffleCards([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]));
```

Comment: I had no idea that JS had arg/array packing/unpacking like this. Do you know where I can find more info on how it works?

Comment: please have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: So in the first line is "value" equal to "topHalf[0]" ? because if so, I think I understand it!

Comment: right and the rest is `slice(1)`.

Comment: For "I want to append any remaining elements to the end of the array," you might return `[...bottomHalf]` instead of `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function shuffleCards(topHalf, bottomHalf,results = []) {
    if(topHalf.length===0&&bottomHalf.length===0)return results;
    if (topHalf.length!==0) {
    results.push(topHalf[0])
    } 
    if (bottomHalf.length!==0) {
      results.push(bottomHalf[0])
    }
    return shuffleCards(topHalf.slice(1), bottomHalf.slice(1),results);
}
```